# Multi option custom MsgBox popup window

Tags: excel, popup, msgbox, vba

I am not sure if this is even doable in Macro (VBA). The issue is, if a user enter a value in specific cell (lets say A2). I need to trigger a popup window (similar to MsgBox function) with several option for the user to select in the popup (either a drop down list or Radio buttons). The values in the drop down list or Radio buttons can be populated in the code. I need to let the user select the option "value" from the list and then can click OK or Cancel. The value that the user selected would be display in the same cell. I checked online and it seems like there are very small selections for the MsgBox function. Can this be done??

Thanks,

Comment: You can do it with a UserForm, triggered by the Worksheet_Change event.  See here for an overview of userforms: http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm01.html

Comment: Alternately, you could probably just use data validation to make a drop-down list.  Then the user can select his choice from the cell itself.  See here for more info: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal01.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use Data Validation to make a drop-down list.

If you go to Data-Data Validation-Allow-List you can create a drop-down list of all values you want. Store all of the values you want in the drop-down list on another sheet and just set it as the Source.

Any other issues let me know.